# Integrate CKEditor in JSP

Tags: jsp, ckeditor, fckeditor

I am using CKEditor in my website. Earlier there was FCKeditor. But it was not compatible with Google Chrome and hence I decided to go with CKEditor.
Below screen shot shows how I am using it:

[image]

Here there are 2 select box:

1. select verse
2. select format

In verse options when I click on **New** button it opens a page with editor as below:

[image]

Here I can type in text and click on **Save** button it gets added to the select verse dropdown.
This is how I can add new verse. So far no issue.
Next when I select any option from dropdown(select verse) and click on **Edit** button it should open the editor with already added text inside it. But it is showing the text outside editor.
[image]

I am integrating CKEditor with JSP.

**My JSP Code:**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://ckeditor.com" prefix="ckeditor" %>
<ckeditor:editor editor="textValue" basePath="ckeditor/">
        <%=textDesc%>
</ckeditor:editor>
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value='https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.0/standard/ckeditor.js'/>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
                                    CKEDITOR
                                            .replace(
                                                    'ckeditor',
                                                    {
                                                        filebrowserBrowseUrl : '<s:url value="/forckeditor" />'
                                                    //uiColor : '#9AB8F3'
                                                    });
                                </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you might want to give a try to new version: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-java-core, https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-java-samples. It is still under development but what is missing is mainly documentation (the code works). I recommend this version because it uses CKEditor 4.x which is compatible with e.g. IE11.

**About your issue** - I think there is a problem in a way how you load data into CKEditor. The `editor:editor` tag (which is in fact "insert editor tag") has `value` attribute which you should use to pass data into editor. **These tags do not accept bodies.** I'm not sure why in TLD for version 3.x body-content is set to JSP however it has benn fixed in CKEditor for Java 4.x and body content is now set [correctly](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnamu.html#bnanh) to `empty` value.

Please also see the CKEditor for Java 4 equivalent for this tag https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-java-samples/blob/master/src/main/webapp/samples/insertTag.jsp and keep in mind that you don't need to stick to JSP expressions and you may use EL (which is preferred over discouraged expressions, scriptlets etc.).